# Office 365 REST API v2 AcquireTokenByAuthorization returning with all null values

Tags: .net, outlook, ms-office, office365

I have been following the [tutorial](https://dev.outlook.com/RestGettingStarted/Tutorial/dotnet) on using Office 365 API to be able to create an event on a users calendar, I was able to get the API to retrieve the events and mail but when I changed the scope to Calendars.ReadWrite the Token would only return null values as per the SS below
[image]
I've had a look around for a solution to this but havn't been able to find how to fix it, or what I may have done wrong.
The only thing that I have different from the tutorial is the redirect URL and the Scopes, I have signed the App up on the registration portal as there tutorial aswell.
**Edit**
I just tried a Fiddler trace, from what I can tell under the properties there were the following flags

**Update**:
I tried doing the tutorial on a new clean project and it worked fine, I was able to post a event to the test user account without a problem, im not sure what that means, going to try starting over on the proper project again.

**Update 2**
So after just copying the code out of the other project and into this one it has just been working, I recreated my app registration, I think that was what went wrong somehow, either way, working now

```
== FLAGS ==================
BitFlags: [ClientPipeReused, ServerPipeReused, LoadedFromSAZ] 0x218
...
X-SERVERSOCKET: REUSE ServerPipe#10
```

Comment: After changing the scope are you reclogging on? The user has to consent to those new scopes. If you are and it still isn't working, I'd recommend getting a Fiddler trace and seeing what's going over the wire.

Comment: @JasonJohnston Thanks for the reply, yes the user had to re consent to the app, I made sure to check that it's asking for full calendar access. I'll give fiddler a try and update the post if I don't find the issue

Comment: @JasonJohnston My first time using Fiddler but I think I might have found the issue, I wasn't too sure what too look for but the entry with the URL that included the authorize code was red and included the flags in the above post